# Why does my calculator always gives me 0 when multiplied and divide while addition and subtraction is working fine?

Tags: c

I'm just trying to make a calculator in the C language. When I use addition and subtraction, the program is working perfectly but, when I try to divide or multiply, the program is just returning an error, no matter what inputs I give.

Here is my code. In this, I simply just used `goto` statements instead of loops for multiple user inputs like 1+2+3+.... and saving the previous value back to variable `b`, then ask another value and save in variable `c`.

I just can't figure out my mistakes, and any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, d;
    double b=0,c=0;
    printf("This is a CLI Based calculator program!\nSelect what do you want to do?!");
    Restart:        //If user still want to continue with current results
    printf("\n1: Addition\t\t2: Subtraction\n3: Multiplication\t4: Divide\n");
    printf("\nChoose option:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    //Check if user has previously used the program or not
    if(b==0) {
        printf("Enter First Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
    } else {
        printf("\nYour Previous result is :%d", b);
        printf("\nEnter Another Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        goto Continue;
    }
    printf("Enter Second Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    Continue:       //Resume process from here if user wants to continue
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            printf("This is Addition: %d\n", b+c);
            b = b+c;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("This is subtraction: %d\n", b-c);
            b = b-c;
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("This is Multiplication: %d\n", b*c);
            b = b*c;
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("This is division: %d\n", b/c);
            b = b/c;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Oops! Seems like you entered wrong option, Select Again!");
            goto Restart;
    }
    //Check if User want to continue with previous result or not
    printf("Do you want to continue?\n1: Yes\t\t2: No!\n");
    printf("\nChoose option:");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    if (d==1){
        goto Restart;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nThank You! For using the calculator.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&b)` -> `scanf("%f",&b)`. Same with `c`. You need to read about formats.

Comment: @P__J__ no, it needs `%lf`. Also `printf("This is division: %d\n", b/c);` is incorrect.

Comment: OT: Always check the value return by `scanf` Like: `if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1) { // error handling };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line `scanf("%d",&b);` (and other, similar ones) is wrong. To read in a `double` value, you need the `%lf` format specifier (`%d` is for decimal integers).

So, change that to `scanf("%lf",&b);` (and make equivalent changes elsewhere, as required), and try again.

For `printf` you have the same issue. Here `printf("This is Multiplication: %d\n", b*c);` the use of `%d` is wrong. Use `%f` for printing a double.

Comment: `%f` is for double

Comment: `%lf ` is for `double` and `printf` is also incorrect, which needs `%f`. Functions `scanf()` and `printf()` are perversely different.

Comment: @P__J__ `%f` for float, `%lf` for double

Comment: @P__J__ Although `%f` will work for double in `printf` (a `float` argument is promoted), it is safer to use `%lf`, IMHO; however, for `scanf`, it's a different story, and `%lf` should be used always.

Comment: thank you sir i forgot about data types thank you very much also i fixed printf and scanf now program is working as expected.

Comment: Note that, prior to the C99 spec, using `%lf` in printf actually gives undefined behavior -- the `l` modifier is only defined for integer/char values, not for floating point.  C99 defines it as having no effect on floating point conversions.